# Xcode 6 Use of undeclared identifier

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)cancel {
    [self.lock lock];
    if (![self isFinished] && ![self isCancelled]) {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];
        _cancelled = YES;
        [super cancel];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isCancelled"];

        // Cancel the connection on the thread it runs on to prevent race conditions
        [self performSelector:@selector(cancelConnection) onThread:[[self class] networkRequestThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO modes:[self.runLoopModes allObjects]];
    }
    [self.lock unlock];
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have this code. And? What is failing?

Comment: Oh sorry ;) The _cancelled = YES; line is getting the error: Use of undeclared identifier

Comment: Do you have the corresponding ivar declared, or a `@property (...) cancelled` in your class?

Comment: Yes '@property (readwrite, nonatomic, assign, getter = isCancelled) BOOL cancelled;'

Comment: Where does the `[super cancel]` come from? What's your superclass? You need to tell us more.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @DanielJuhlSørensen the issue is about the AFNetworking and I also just updated my pods and got this issue with _cancel = YES line. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Cyrille, I faced with the same issue. I think we just need to rename question and add some extra information what actually Daniel made, but I think we should not down vote him. Let's help. I just want to confirmation that the issue is came from AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue also described [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2409).

You can find a line: "When i synthesised it my own self, it started working fine.
@synthesize cancelled = _cancelled".

So just find `@implementation AFURLConnectionOperation` and add synthesize: `@synthesize cancelled = _cancelled;` it should remove the issue with `AFURLConnectionOperation` if it came from there.